# Redshift COPY command failing - Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I have a scenario where I get the last modified file from a specific S3 folder and there by I want to COPY the csv data into a redshift table. Below is the code:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
    list_of_s3_objs = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket="demo", Prefix="myfolder/")
    
    # Returns a bunch of json
    contents = list_of_s3_objs["Contents"]
    
    #get last modified
    sorted_contents = sorted(list_of_s3_objs['Contents'], key=lambda d: d['LastModified'], reverse=True)

    recent_file_uploaded = 's3://demo/'+sorted_contents[0].get('Key')
```

This yields output like - 's3://demo/myfolder/myfile.csv'

Next, I want to execute COPY command on this file. Below is the code:

```
#def redshift():
    print('Redshift connection')
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host="myhostname",port='5439',database="mydb", user=username, password=passw, sslmode='require')
    print('connection success')
    
    cur = conn.cursor();

    # Begin your transaction
    cur.execute("begin;")
    print('Begin transaction')
    
    cur.execute("copy mytable from recent_file_uploaded credentials 'aws_access_key_id='ACCESS_KEY';aws_secret_access_key='SECRET_KEY'' csv;")
    # Commit your transaction
    cur.execute("commit;")
    print("Copy executed fine!")
```

In the above code, the cur.execute is failing with a syntax error at

```
copy mytable from recent_file_uploaded credential...
                  ^
```

Not sure what's wrong here. I tried making it as `copy mytable from ''recent_file_uploaded''...` still same error. Can someone point me on where the COPY command is wrong pls?

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure you can't have single quotes inside single quotes without escaping them

Answer (score 1):

[Authorization parameters - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-authorization.html) shows an example using an Access Key and Secret Key as:

```
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=<temporary-access-key-id>;aws_secret_access_key=<temporary-secret-access-key>;token=<temporary-token>'
```

It would *seem* like you do not need to quote the individual elements. Admittedly, the documentation is confusing because it does show some examples with quotes, but they are not using *credentials-args* syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I am able to fix it with below syntax:

```
  copy_query = f"COPY mytable FROM '{recent_file_uploaded}' IAM_ROLE 'my-role-arn' FILLRECORD CSV;"
    cur.execute(copy_query)
```

this fixed the problem. It's the way python parameters are passed into the COPY command.